# Question about the mean of sampling distribution of means

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,X_2,.....,X_n$ deonte the i.i.d random variables for a random sample of size $n$.Then the mean of sample is a random variable defined by
$$\bar{X}=\frac{X_1+X_2+.....+X_n}{n}$$

Let $f(x)$ be the pdf of some given population from which we draw a sample of size $n$,We have that "The mean of the sampling distribution of means denote by $E[\bar{X}]=\mu$" ,where $\mu$ is the mean of the population.
I want to know the proof of this, below is what I tried.

$E[\bar{X}]=E[\frac{X_1+X_2+.....+X_n}{n}]=\frac{1}{n}E[X_1+X_2+....+X_n]=\frac{1}{n}\{E[X_1]+E[X_2]+....+E[X_n]\}$

Now I think the reason that each $E[X_i]=\mu$ is that since all $X_i's$ are i.i.d, But I want to know why this is, like some mathematical proof for this that all $E[X_i]=\mu$.

Comment: Do you know the mathematical definition of $\mu$? And do you know what i.i.d. means?

Comment: Yes,suppose we have a population of size $N$ then $\mu=E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}f(x_i)$ and by i.i.d we have that they all have same distribution.

Comment: The [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) is used in combination with integrals, while the [pmf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) is used with sums. Problems with *population* can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.01732.pdf). Yes, I'm knitpicking, but the answer to your question is in the definitions, so I enforce the definitions. We know that $f(x)$ is the pmf of the population, and $\mu=E[X]=\sum_ix_if(x_i)$ is the mean (or expectation) of the population. What is the population, what is $X$, how does $X$ relate to $X_1,\dots,X_n$?

Comment: $X_{i}$'s are the observed values of pdf of the random variable $X$,where $X$ is random variable associated with he population

Comment: In this context, it is okay to define $X$ as the population. If we take this definition, then the *samples* $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are *independent* and *identically distributed* with the same distribution as the *population* $X$. Here, the same distribution means that $X$ and all $X_i$ have the *pmf* $f(x)$, which, again, are the point probabilities here. In particular, this means that $\mathbb E[X_i]=\sum_{j=1}^Nf(x_j)x_j=\mathbb E[X]=\mu$.

Comment: But by definition if we see, since we have sample size $n$ ,so I think $\mathbb{E}[X_j]=\sum_{j=1}^{n}f(x_j)x_j$, here only I have doubt.

Comment: The number $n$ of samples is not the same as the size $N$ of the support (or population size $N$)

Comment: yes,as we only have $X_1,...,X_n$  in sample then how you have written $\sum_{j=1}^{N}x_if(x_i)$?? it should be from 1 to $n$?

Comment: We have $X,X_1,\dots,X_n\in\{x_1,\dots,x_N\}$ with $\mathbb P(X=x_j)=\mathbb P(X_i=x_j)=f(x_j)$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ and $j=1,\dots,N$. I hope this helps to distinguish the different notions. The $X,X_i$ are random variables, the $x_j$ are values, the possible outcomes. When you throw dice ten times, you have $n=10$ samples, and $N=6$ possible outcomes. The pmf is $f(1)=\dots=f(6)=\frac{1}{6}$ and the expectation is $\mu=\frac{1}{6}\cdot 1+\dots+\frac{1}{6}\cdot 6=3.5$. The mean $\bar X$ depends on the actual outcomes, say if we get ten times a $1$, then $\bar X=1$, hence $\bar X$ is random.